# How to set the background color for button in Android during run time?

Tags: android

I have to set the background color during run time, i am using "setBackgroundColor(R.color.focusColor)" . but its nots working.

Answer (score 3):

use setBackgroundColor(Color.color)" or setBackgroundColor("#000000");

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `PorterDuff.Mode` enum with its [properties](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html).

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.yourButtonResId)).getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF00FF00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Here's the result containing an unchanged default Pass button and a Submit button on which I applied the line above:

[image]

More details on this matter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color).

Answer (score 0):

May be [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499208/android-setting-text-view-color-from-java-code) can help you a bit.

In a nutshell you have to use `this.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange)` in argument.

**EDIT: ** Pasted a wrong code. Edited

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

To Google travelers, if this is a Drawable update (e.g. you are going to update your button that already have a drawable, such as `button.getBackground.doStuff()`) you need to use Button.invalidateSelf().

[`public void invalidateSelf()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#invalidateSelf%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);` BLUE can be replaced by the color you want if its available!

Answer (score 0):

its simplest way
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.yourButtonResId)).setBackground(#ffffff);