# Create button background by color in runtime

Tags: android

In my app, I have the selector below.

Is possible to create a similar selector, by color instead of by image-drawable, but at runtime?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item 
        android:state_window_focused="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_button_orange_normal" />

    <item  
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_button_orange_pressed" />

    <item 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_button_orange_focused" />

    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_button_orange_normal" />

</selector>
```

I have tried the function below to create the selector in runtime, but I need to create a round button, not square.

Is this possible?

> ```
> private StateListDrawable makeSelector(int color)
> {
>   StateListDrawable res = new StateListDrawable();
>     res.setExitFadeDuration(400);
>     res.setAlpha(45);
>     ShapeDrawable d = new ShapeDrawable();
>     res.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, new ColorDrawable(ColorUtilities.decrease(color, 0x003030)));
>     res.addState(new int[] {}, new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
>     return res;   
> }
> ```

Edit again... I have found the way to create round selectors...

> ```
> private static ShapeDrawable getRoundShapeDrawable(int color)     
> {
>   ShapeDrawable shape_drawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
>   shape_drawable.getPaint().setColor(color);
>   return shape_drawable;  
> }
>
> public static StateListDrawable getRoundShapeSelector(int normal_color, int pressed_color)
> {
>   ShapeDrawable normal_shape_drawable = getRoundShapeDrawable(normal_color), pressed_shape_drawable = getRoundShapeDrawable(pressed_color);
>   StateListDrawable state_list_drawable = new StateListDrawable();
>   state_list_drawable.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, pressed_shape_drawable);
>   state_list_drawable.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_focused }, pressed_shape_drawable);
>   state_list_drawable.addState(new int[] { }, normal_shape_drawable);
>   return state_list_drawable;   
> }
> ```

Comment: You can define color in  your `android:drawable=` attribute as `android:drawable="@color/your_color"` or `android:drawable="#ffffff"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551959/how-to-set-the-background-color-for-button-in-android-during-run-time

Answer (score 1):

You can use "StateListDrawable"

[StateListDrawable](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=13SeVoCEHsiL8QevybOwCg#q=StateListDrawable%20android)

and add state in it.
Let me know if you face problem in implementing this.

Comment: Edited que question. Main problem is that I'm not capable to create a round button with this code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a round button. Then you can use layer-list then add this drawable xml as a Layer.

Eg. How to create round button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="40dp" />
            <solid android:color="#fff" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="40dp" />
            <solid android:color="#d3d3d3" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="40dp" />
            <solid android:color="#EBEBEB" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/wl_btn_bg_shape"
        android:bottom="6dp"
        android:left="6dp"
        android:right="6dp"
        android:top="6dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="40dp" />
            <solid android:color="#00caa8" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

create and save about code in drawable as wl_btn_bg.xml

Now you need to add this xml as view background

```
LayerDrawable layers = (LayerDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wl_btn_bg);
view.setBackground(layers);
```

and if you want to change the color of selector then you need to add following lines in layers

```
LayerDrawable layers = (LayerDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wl_btn_bg);
        GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable) (layers.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.wl_btn_bg_shape));
shape.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ff6655"));
```

Done....

Comment: Thanks, but the main goal of the question is to update the selector colors in runtime